# is it possible to get google maps to display all road names?

Tags: google-maps

I am using a web based program that ultizes google maps to break up a town into sections. Which can then be printed on various sizes. What I cannot seem to figure out how to do is to customize google maps to display the names of all the roads on a given section of the town without zooming in very closely.

I want to keep a larger section of the town displayed and then print it out a full sized piece of paper which is large enough to provide plenty of space to display all the road names. I have figured out how to hide all road names, display only highways etc., but nothing I seem to do will allow me to have all the road names displayed.

I have been using [mapstyle.withgoogle.com](http://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) to produce a JSON which is then pasted into the custom google map setting. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can depict all roads if they have been updated. otherwise, Apple maps comes as alternative where every small detailed changes can be viewed.